# Meaning of 'I will have you know'

Tags: meaning

The sentence is from a novel 'Life of Pi', and here is the part.

> Still, answer the question, any regrets now?
>   *I don't think about it*.
>   The very definition of an animal. That is all you are.
>   *And what are you?*
>   A human being, **I will have you know**.

Is this sentence similar to 'I will let you know'?

Comment: No similarity at all.  "I will have you know" is a rather emphatic emphasis to an answer, contradiction or statement of fact and used to slighty chide the listener. So when Pi says, "A human being, I will have you know" what he's really saying is, what kind of a stupid question is, "And what are you?"

Answer (score 1):

A meaning of *have* is to compel, be obligated to do/make, or force.

> I have to go to school.
>
> I have to know this to pass the exam.

So "I will have you know" is meaning "I am obligated to make you know."

That's what it means literally, but this is a well-known saying that has an underlying meaning as "@Joe Dark" describes perfectly in the comments.

Comment: But the obligation is on the hearer's part, not the speaker's.  It is like "you are obligated (I compel you) to know this."