# What does the verb ''have' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, verb-usage

In this following definition does the verb ''have'' play in causative meaning?  or what?

Please, simplify it to me...

> for oneself (idiom):
> rather than have someone else (do or share
> something)
> She did not like just hearing of other's travels. She
> wanted to see Europe for herself.

Source:
(Merriam-Webster.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of 'I will have you know'.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67876/meaning-of-i-will-have-you-know) Also [What is difference between have/get/make someone do something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146862/) and ["Have someone do/doing someting", "be having someone do/doing something" in context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/254958/) and [The difference in meaning between "Have someone do something" and "Get someone to do something"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/240399/), among others.

Answer (score 0):

It is the causative sense of have.  A definition of this (from wiktionary) is

> cause to, by a command, request or invitation.

Here it would normally mean that one has asked someone to do something and they did it.  So, to do something "for oneself" means the opposite of "asking somebody else to do it for you".